# Conditional React Forms

Tags: reactjs, formik, react-hook-form

I would like to start off by saying I am still pretty new to React and hope I explain this issue clearly.

I am trying to make a conditional form using react-hook-form or formik that has conditional fields.

question 1:
answer a
answer b
answer c

Based on the answer from question 1, question 2 could be different based on what your answer for question 1 is.  I would like for this to be a multi-step form as well.  So you will see question 1, click next, and based upon your answer to question 1 the correct question 2 appears.

Basically, all I would like for someone to do is point me towards a tutorial or documentation that explains how to do this.  I have tried searching, but I don't think I know the correct terminology to search for.

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: Hey Alex, take a look here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKpoAhugjUc

Comment: @tdranv  Thanks for the suggestion.  I am completely unfamiliar with TypeScript.  Is this something that I should consider using?

Comment: Not necessarily. I would say it's a more advanced topic but since it is a superset of JavaScript, it is fairly intuitive to understand. This tutorial is fairly good as well: https://css-tricks.com/the-magic-of-react-based-multi-step-forms/